# Re-exports not properly bundled with Webpack 5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bundle, webpack-5

When bundling my web-application, I have realised that **re-exports** of *(some)* modules do not work as expected. I have tried multiple **optimization settings** but so far with no success.

###### Setup

So basically I have the following setup

```
config/
  webpack.config.ts
  package.json

frontend/
  apps/
    app1/
      src/
        index.tsx
        App.tsx
        ...
  packages/
    test/
      index.ts
      testFunc.ts
      test1Func.ts
      Test.tsx
      Test1.tsx
```

So I **run** webpack from `config` with the **entry point** `frontend/apps/app1/index.tsx` which imports `App.tsx` *(standard React application)*.

This all works fine but I have realised that when produce a **production build** from **app1**, unused exports in my `App.tsx` appear in the bundle. To clarify

```js
import { testFunc } from 'packages/test' // <- `packages` is an alias

const App: React:FC = () => {
  const t = testFunc();
  return <>Hello World!</>;
}
```

will include `Test.tsx`, `Test1.tsx` and 'test1Func.ts' in the bundle. My `index.ts` in `test/` looks like

```js
export { testFunc } from './testFunc';
export { test1Func } from './test1Func';
export { Test } from './Test';
export { Test1 } from './Test1';
```

I should mention that `testFunc1.ts` contains a `useEffect` hook because I found that as soon as I have react related code, there is no tree shaking for the source anymore. So

```js
// test1Func.ts
export const test1Func = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // do nothing
  }, []);
  return "Test 1";
}
```

However, if I import my files directly, eg. `import { testFunc } from 'packages/test/testFunc'`, everything works as expected and only `test` appears in the bundle. This also applies to the other test components:

###### App import tests

`testFunc`

- import via `index.ts` & use in `App.tsx` => bundles **all** files inside `test/` ❌
- import via `import { testFunc } from 'packages/test/testFunc'` & use in `App.tsx` => **only** `testFunc.ts` is included in the bundle ✅
- import via `import { testFunc } from 'packages/test/testFunc'` & **don't** use in `App.tsx` => nothing gets included in the bundle ✅

`testFunc1` | `Test` | `Test1` <- they all behave the same

- import via `index.ts` & use in `App.tsx` => bundles **all but `testFunc`** ❌
- import via `import { test1Func } from 'packages/test/test1Func'` & use in `App.tsx` => **only** `test1Func.ts` is included in the bundle ✅
- import via `import { test1Func } from 'packages/test/testFunc'` & **don't** use in `App.tsx` => nothing gets included in the bundle ✅

I guess this is just a configuration error, although I have already tried multiple different optimisation settings. The closest probably is the `sideEffects` option but so far, this also did not have any effect.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!

As guessed, I had Webpack's `optimization.sideEffects` property misconfigured. `sideEffects` is necessary for proper [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

However, in order to get this work properly there are **2 destinations** where you have to set the sideEffects property:

- your `package.json` *(in my case in every package I use in my monorepo)*
- and in the `webpack.config.ts`

###### Solution

The admittedly very confusing thing is that you will have to set

- `sideEffects: false` in the `package.json`
- and `sideEffects: true` in the `optimization` section in your `webpack.config.ts`

[Here's](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/15854) a bit more if you are interested.